# Static UITableView and setting it's data after it's been loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static `UITableView` and 2 `UITextFields` as `IBOutlets`. I need to set text of these fields depending on `NSUserDefaults`. So there are two ways to do this: in `-(void)viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`. Tried them both with no result. Values in defaults are checked, textfields connected properly. Some code:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;
```

Implementation example of one field:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
self.someLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"someText"];
}
```

Fields are empty.Any clues?

Comment: Have you logged self.someLabel in viewDidLoad to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar yes, did this million times

Comment: @rdelmar maybe the problem is that I do this outside of delegate methods like cellForRowAtIndexPath? I mean these labels are subviews in table view cells. I am trying to access them directly via IBOutlets. But I see nothing bad in such approach. I also tried to reload table view after setting text value in viewDidLoad.Unsuccessfully.

Comment: You shouldn't even be implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath or any of the other data source methods (delegate methods are ok). If you are, that could be the problem.

Comment: Now I didn't implement them, cause that's the idea behind static table view. Can you,please,reproduce this? I really think there is tiny detail I am missing.

Comment: If you log self.someLabel.text, does it return the correct string? I can't see how this isn't working if you have a valid string and a connected outlet (unless your text is the same color as the background). Do you see the label at all (if not, give it a background color to make sure it's visible).

Comment: I see it, it has a placeholder. NSLog says it contains empty string.

Comment: Then [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"someText"] must not be returning anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65785/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-efimovd).

Comment: WOW, I just tried to set this to static string like @"123" and it worked! Can't really understand why. NSLoged NSUserDefaults and the value is here.

Answer (score 0):

Yep,it's my fault that I forgot to synchronize NSUserDefaults. UITableView works properly. And you can access desired objects via outlets(if they are established) with no fear.My bad.